# Why is the /var/log/chrony folder empty?

Tags: linux, redhat, ntp, chrony

We are using chrony in order to sync our Red Hat (7.2) servers with NTP servers.

In order to do so, we've configured the `logdir /var/log/chrony` in `chrony.conf` and restarted the chrony via `systemctl restart chronyd`.

But still, the folder `/var/log/chrony` is empty without any logs.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As well as having a `logdir` defined, you must also enable logging with the `log` directive.  Here's an extract from the default RHEL 7.2 `/etc/chrony.conf`:

```
...
# Specify directory for log files.
logdir /var/log/chrony

# Select which information is logged.
#log measurements statistics tracking
```

You must uncomment the last line (or include another relevant `log ...` directive) to obtain logging.

Comment: For more advanced usage there is also an option to [run `chronyd` in debug mode](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4065381).